# table jumps when vertically scrolled

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how to ask this properly as I don't really understand what's happening. The page has a .5em margin on all sides. The table has no margin or padding settings, so they are default. The first row is fixed so it doesn't scroll when the table is scrolled. However, when the table is scrolled, the top row jumps to the top of the viewport, ignoring the margin. When scrolled up it returns to its original position when the top of the table is reached. I added a 1-pixel border so I could see the table separate from the margin. Changing border-collapse from collapse to separate had no effect. As there is only one table I am manipulating it using the table and thead selectors only, corresponding to the table and thead tags in the html.

Edit: I found the key to keeping the table stationary. I changed the top attribute of the thead selector from 0 to .5em and it worked. However, now the table contents below the first row overflow into the body margin area. I tried using overflow:hidden and overflow-y:hidden in the table css, but it had no effect.

The pertinent css:

```
body { margin:.5em .5em .5em .5em; }
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
/* freeze panes */
/* rows */
thead {
  position:sticky;
  top:0; /* changed this from 0 to .5em */
  min-height:15px;
  height:15px;
  z-index:50;
  background-color:white;
}
```

You can see the page here: [Compares](https://wayneca.neocities.org/Sokoban/Compares.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The css is as follows:

```
body {
  margin:.5em .5em .5em .5em;
  font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size:12pt;
}
table {
  display:block;
  border:none;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
  height:41.5em;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
/* freeze panes */
/* rows */
thead {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  min-height:15px;
  height:15px;
  z-index:50;
  background-color:white;
}
```

You can see the page here: [Compares](https://wayneca.neocities.org/Sokoban/Compares.html)